# How do I explain this? Is it generic method? What type of method is it and how a method has map?

Tags: java

New To java. What topic it is related to?
What type of method is it and how a method has map?

```
public static Map<Character, Integer> countDuplicateCharactersV1(String str)
```

Comment: The **return type** comes after `static` and before the method name (`countDuplicateCharactersV1`) in this case. The method **returns** a `Map`.

Comment: What as `public static int count()` - what is the `int` there?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it generic method?

No.  There is no generic type parameter declaration.  A generic method might look like this:

```
public static <T> Map<Character, Integer> countDuplicateCharactersInThing(T thing)
```

The type parameter(s) appear before the method's return type and are in `<...>`s.  In the above: `<T>`.

In your example, `Map<Character, Integer>` is the return type.  (It doesn't **start** with a `<`!)

> What type of method is it and how a method has map?

It is a `static` method that **returns** a `Map<Character, Integer>`. It presumably summarizes the duplicate characters in the given string.